# 2 column layout with 1 sticky

Tags: wordpress, scroll, multiple-columns, sticky

I'm trying to achieve a behavior like on this page: https://nago.com/collections/spring-sale/products/bluza-z-bawelny-organicznej-17-14-mist-grey using CSS only.

I'd like to have 2 columns scrollable, when I scroll to the bottom of the right column then it should stay sticky. The scroll should be applied then only to the left column and when I scroll to the bottom of the left column both columns should not be sticky anymore.

Is it possible to achieve this only with CSS? I'm building my page in Wordpress.